# Primary key not set in JoinTable on INSERT (Eclipselink)

Tags: eclipselink, primary-key, join

I habe two tables which are have a manytomany relation via a join table. Entity L is the "Main" entity
The problem is that EclipseLink dosen't set the primary key in the join table when there are new entities in the collection of the manytomany value.
When I load entities of L the collection is filled with entities of K. When I delete one entity in the collection and save L the link row in
L_K_L is deleted by EclipseLink. But when I add a entity of K to the collection and save the entity L I got exceptions and it shows among others:

```
INSERT INTO L_K_L (FKEY_K, FKEY_L) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="kategorien" sql="INSERT INTO L_K_L (FKEY_K, FKEY_L) VALUES (?, ?)")
```

What do I have to do to say EclipseLink to use the sequence generator of LKL and to use the column PKEY for the join table on insert?

Here are the tables and classes.
The primary keys are generated via oracle sequences. The sequences are named like SEQ_TABLLE_NAME_PKEY.

Thanks for help

Karsten

```
TABLE L:
PKEY NUMBER(10)  -- PRIMARY KEY
NAME VARCHAR2(10)

TABLE K:
PKEY NUMBER(10)  -- PRIMARY KEY
NAME VARCHAR(10)
FKEY_K NUMBER(10)

Join table L_K_L
PKEY NUMBER(10)  -- PRIMARY KEY
FKEY_L NUMBER(10)  -- foreign key to table L
FKEY_K NUMBER(10)  -- foreign key to table K
```

Now the model classes:

Class L:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="L")
public class L  implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="L_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="L_SEQ", sequenceName="SEQ_L_PKEY", allocationSize=1)
  private Long pkey;
  @NotNull
  @javax.validation.constraints.Size(min=1, max=80)
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name="L_K_L",
              joinColumns=
                   @JoinColumn(name="FKEY_L"),
              inverseJoinColumns=
                   @JoinColumn(name="FKEY_K")
  )
  private Collection<K> k;
```

Class K:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="K")
public class K implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="K_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="K_SEQ", sequenceName="SEQ_K_PKEY", allocationSize=1)
  private Long pkey;
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "FKEY_K", referencedColumnName = "PKEY")
  private K k;
```

Class LKL

```
@Entity
@Table(name="L_K_L")
public class LKL implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="LKL_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="LKL_SEQ", sequenceName="SEQ_L_K_L_PKEY", allocationSize=1)
  private Long pkey;
  private L l;
  private K k;
```

Comment: Why does your join table have a pk field?  If you want to use it as an entity, you cannot use a ManyToMany mapping that bypasses the entity.  Instead, you need to make relationships to/from Entity L and K, with L and K having OneToMany relationships to it.

Comment: Can you show me the Fields with annotations in the three classes? at the end I need a Collection of K in the Class L. 
The underlaying database is over 10 years and that it was built with primary keys in the join tables.

Comment: You don't have a collection of Ks though, you have a collection of LKLs each of which have a single K associated.  You can abstract this out from your business layer if needed, but it might be better to use the LKLs since they do have identity that should probably be maintained.